# Reasons why not to use the built-in authentication system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

This is something I have wanted to ask for a long time.

I have been using FormsAuthentication, Authorization, Membership and the Role providers for many projects, but come to think about it, each of them has always struck me as being a bit clunky. And even harder to extend.

When I look at the code I need to implement (and understand) to authenticate users in ASP.NET I find it a bit strange that over in PHP and RoR world they pretty much just check for a username and password in a database, set a session and redirect to another page.

So, what arguments is there that should hold me back from implementing a simpler approach for handling logins and perhaps user management ?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure why you think ASP.NET is any different from what you described the PHP world is. Of all the pieces you listed (FormsAuth, Authorization, Membership, Roles), only FormsAuthentication is mandatory. And it does exactly what you described. If you don't already have a user store, you add Membership. Authorization and Role are completely optional.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of the Membership framework, but it has one big advantage over roll-your-own:

The framework takes care of some of the security concerns for you (for example, storing password hashes rather than full passwords.)  and is well-tested. Security-related code is often complex and poorly implemented and tested by people who don't have a deep understanding of it.  Poor implementation leads to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: With the fairly new Crypto class you can roll out that functionality very easily. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Yes, it's not hard to generate hashes.  That was one example, salting the passwords is another.  There are more.  The point is, even if you have all the building blocks, putting them together correctly is hard.

Comment: The above method generates both a hash and a salt, in a single value. http://brockallen.com/2012/10/19/password-management-made-easy-in-asp-net-with-the-crypto-api/

Comment: Now add password complexity requirements, lockout based on invalid attempts, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have substantially answered your own question. If your project requirements are satisfied using the "out of the box" Forms Authentication et al, then I wouldn't work too hard trying to extend or modify it.

Many times, the simpler schemes aren't very secure. There are some systems that literally store the plaintext password in a database, and do nothing to protect the password in transit (over the wire). So simple is a tradeoff (sometimes) for secure.

Keep in mind, too, that the "out of the box" stuff is almost certainly better-tested than anything you'll build yourself (not you personally, but generally, so no offense :) ), eg hashing, perhaps key exchanging, authentication, all that stuff. The security package, if nothing else, is designed as a way to avoid having to roll all that low-level stuff from scratch.